# Running the animation after scrolling to the block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have function that works after window.onload, but how to run it just after scrolled to the needed . I understand that using jQuery is easier, but I need to do in native JS.

```
window.onload = function move() {
    var width = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("myBar");
    var maxValue = document.getElementsByClassName('max-value');

      for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      var params = {
        elem: elem[i],
        maxElem: maxValue[i],
        width: width,
        interval: null
      };
      params.interval = setInterval(frame, 20, params);
    }

  function frame(aParams) {
    if (aParams.width >= aParams.maxElem.dataset.max) {
      clearInterval(aParams.interval);
    } else {
        aParams.width++;
        aParams.elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        aParams.elem.style.width = aParams.width + '%';
        aParams.maxElem.innerHTML = aParams.width + '%';
    }
  };   

};
```

https://codepen.io/Slava91/pen/PjpGGr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will trigger the animation again when you will scroll near to the ul element. #percentage is the id I have given to the ul element in your html.

```
window.onload = move();

  function move() {
    var width = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("myBar");
    var maxValue = document.getElementsByClassName('max-value');

      for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      var params = {
        elem: elem[i],
        maxElem: maxValue[i],
        width: width,
        interval: null
      };
      params.interval = setInterval(frame, 20, params);
    }

  function frame(aParams) {
    if (aParams.width >= aParams.maxElem.dataset.max) {
      clearInterval(aParams.interval);
    } else {
        aParams.width++;
        aParams.elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        aParams.elem.style.width = aParams.width + '%';
        aParams.maxElem.innerHTML = aParams.width + '%';
    }
  };   

}
isScrolled = false;
window.onscroll = function loadItBack(){
  var rec = document.getElementById("percentage").getBoundingClientRect();
  if(window.scrollY > 600 && !isScrolled){
    isScrolled = true;
    move();
  }else if(window.scrollY < 600){
    isScrolled = false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For your every li, you can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to execute your animation.

Don't forget to set a flag once animation completed, else, it will execute on every scroll.